# characteristic equation of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $x''+3x'+2x=4.$ ($''=2nd $ derivative, $'=1st$ derivative)

Determine the characteristic equation of this differential equation.

I'm having a hard time doing this because of that $4$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen characteristic equation defined for a non-homogeneous differential equation.

Comment: I agree with Git. You should do it for $x''(t)+3x'(t)+2x(t)=0$

Comment: Maybe they meant to replace the $4$ by a $0$, solve homogeneously, and worry about the nonhomogeneous part of the solutions later?

Comment: by characteristic equation does she mean the characteristic equation of $$x''+3x'+2x=0$$??

Comment: It is not uncommon to talk about the "characteristic equation" of a non-homogeneous equation meaning the characteristic equation of the corresponding homogeneous equation, to avoid unnecessary lengthiness because there really is no ambiguity. So you're supposed to ignore the $4$.

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam hmmm maybe $r^2+3r+2 = 0$ and that factors out to $(r+1)(r+2)=0$. Since $ r = -1,-2$ there are two unique real roots so the answer is $y=c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{-2x}$. Though I was never given a question about characteristic equations when I took the first part of the differential equations course. In fact, there wasn't any question at all. Maybe it's worded differently?

Comment: well this can only be confirmed by @user122415..

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam I'm looking down at an answer.. it seems that I got this right... well the $y_h$ part that is because I forgot to calculate the $Y_p$ and then finish it with $y_h+y_p$. But there is a type of problem on that and it's called Solving an equation by using the Undetermined Method of Coefficients .

Comment: @usukidoll You mean *Method of Undetermined Coefficients*. If the method itself were undetermined, you'd have a hard time using it. :P

Comment: oh yes that's right. I meant to type Method of Undetermined Coefficients, but it was so late at night and I was tired @M.Vinay

Answer (score 3):

The $4$ is the inhomogeneous part of the equation. To evaluate the characteristic equation you have to consider only the homogeneous part:

$x^{\prime\prime} + 3 x^\prime + 2 x = 0$.

The characteristic equation, expressed in terms of a variable $\alpha$, is

$\alpha^2 + 3 \alpha + 2 = 0$.

The solutions are $\alpha = -2$ and $\alpha = -1$.

From this, you can obtain the solution of the homogeneous equation:

$x_h = A e^{-t} + B e^{-2t}$,

where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants that you may probably have to fix using initial conditions.

The particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation is pretty simple because the inhomogeneous term is just a constant:

$x_p = 2$.

Therefore, the general solution of the equation is

$x = A e^{-t} + B e^{-2t} + 2$.